# How to simplify the expression $(E \cup F)\cap(E \cup F^{c})$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$(E \cup F)(E \cup F^{c})$

Is the operator between the 2 parentheses implied to be an intersection, i.e, $(E \cup F)\cap(E \cup F^{c})$?

In this case:

$(E \cup F)\cap(E \cup F^{c})$=$(E\cap E\cup F^{c})\cup(F\cap E\cup F^{c})$?

How do I go about simplifying from there?

Comment: yes it's an intersection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see that $$(E\cup F)\cap(E\cup F^c) = E\cup(F \cap F^c)?$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I see, so it just simplifies to $E$?

Comment: Yes, it does, assuming the set operation between $E\cup F$ and $E \cup F^c$ is intersection, which I presume to be the case here.